# 日本語の方言に対応した形態素解析の辞書はありますか？

Tags: 自然言語処理

標準語のために作られた形態素解析辞書はいろいろありますけど（UniDicとか）、大阪弁などの方言に向ける辞書はありますか？

Comment: 「形態素解析 辞書 方言」で Google 検索するといくつか論文等がヒットしますが、それらは参考になりませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！ざっと目を通しましたけど、すぐ使えるものはまだないようです:(　でも、このプロジェクトは始まったばっかりみたいで、将来はオープン公開するって言います。https://research-er.jp/projects/view/1222048